# JHipster Application produces message "this.driver.matchesElement" in dev mode

Tags: node.js, angular, jhipster, yarnpkg

I have a problem running a JHipster application in Dev. Some developers run smoothly, in others the message "TypeError: this.driver.matchesElement is not a function" is displayed. All computers have the same versions of NPM, Yarn, and Node.

- Node Version: 8.11.0
- NPM Version: 5.6.0
- Yarn Version: 1.7.0

Front-End Application StackTrace:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.driver.matchesElement is not a function
    at TransitionAnimationEngine.processLeaveNode (browser.js?881a:3023)
    at TransitionAnimationEngine.flush (browser.js?881a:3059)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.AnimationEngine.flush (browser.js?881a:3896)
    at eval (animations.js?063e:363)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js?6524:388)
    at Zone.run (zone.js?6524:138)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js?593e:4681)
    at AnimationRendererFactory.end (animations.js?063e:361)
    at DebugRendererFactory2.end (core.js?593e:15096)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js?593e:11563)
defaultErrorLogger
```

Package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.4.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "primeng": "5.2.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.19",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "0.2.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.5",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "3.8.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "8.0.18",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.2",
    "browser-sync": "2.18.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fullcalendar": "3.9.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "4.14.4",
    "html-loader": "0.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.11",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.16",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "source-map": "0.6.1",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "5.5.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.5",
    "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
    "webpack": "3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.1",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.1.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0"
  },
  ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Linux Fedora 27

Comment: I found the solution. This was a problem with version 6.0.4 of angular animations. I updated the project to version 6.0.6 and corrected all dependency warnings. It is now working properly

Comment: Thanks @Braulio. In my case downgrading from 6.0.7 to 6.0.5 worked for me. I was getting same error (TypeError: this.driver.matchesElement is not a function) with 6.0.7 version in my angular application.

npm install @angular/animations@6.0.5 --save

Comment: I am running on Mac, i am still getting the issue.

Comment: @Biranchi, erase your node_modules folder and try 6.0.6 version. If don't work, try downgrade other versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with version 6.0.4 of angular animations. I updated the project to version 6.0.6 and corrected all dependency warnings. It is now working properly

Answer (score 0):

So we had an issue where the system.js file was defining the version to use but the package.json file was getting the most up to date version. This was causing an issue on the front end.

After we removed the version from system.js then it was happy.